# One to many relationship Laravel migration

Tags: laravel, postgresql, migration

I currently have a 1:1 relationship and I need it to be a one to many.
Such that `Job Details` can have multiple results for 1 `Job Search`.

**Job Searches**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('job_searches', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
   });
}
```

**Job Details**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('job_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('job_details_id',11);
        $table->foreign('job_details_id')->references('id')->on('job_searches');    
    });
}
```

The current output I am getting is:

```
Job_Search_Id   
1

Job_Detail_Id
1
```

When adding another result to the `job details` I get:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[23503]:
>   Foreign key violation: 7 ERROR:  insert or update on table
>   "job_details" violates foreign key constraint
>   "job_details_job_details_id_foreign"

I also have stated the relationships in my models

**Job Search Model**

```
class JobSearches extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function job_details(){
          return $this->belongsToMany('App\job_details');
    }
}
```

**Job Details Model**

```
class JobDetails extends Model
{
 protected $primaryKey = 'job_details_id';

 public function job_search(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\job_search');
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Change the migration to:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('job_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('job_search_id');
    });

    Schema::table('job_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('job_search_id')->references('id')->on('job_searches');    
    });
}
```

And the `JobSearch` class:

```
class JobSearch extends Model
{
    public function jobDetails(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\JobDetail');
    }
}
```

And the `JobDetail` class:

```
class JobDetails extends Model
{
    public function jobSearch()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\JobSearch');
    }
}
```

If you'll use the code without modification, it will work for you.

Comment: This doesn't work sadly, the unsignedInteger needs to have a size `11` for it to reference the id in `job_search`. If i do remove that, the the `job_search_id` will always be `null`. When I do include the size, it says it's not allowed due to multiple primary keys being defined.

Comment: @Chocotier since the `id` in `job_searches` is `$table->increments('id');`, the foreign key must be unsigned integer and not `integer, 11`. Just try the code.

Comment: When unsigned integer is used, it produces: `Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column "job_search_id" violates not-null constraint`. Sorry if I explained it wrong initially. (I inserted dummy data into job_search, so theres no reason for it to produce a null violation error).

Comment: @Chocotier if you want it nullbale, just add `->nullable()` to the definition. Or always pass FK.

Comment: When I nullable is used, it always produces  null. The foreign key is not able to pull the ID from `job_search` table to `job_search_id`, thus the `not null violation error` before . I used a factory on the `job_search` table, so it does have an ID to reference to, but it is unable to.

Comment: @Chocotier not it's not. `nullable()` means the column can be `null` or contain a value. Why don't you just try the code?

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand the problem still. I have tried the code and the column is always being null when using `nullable()`.

Comment: @Chocotier ok, I've explained how `nullable` works, I gave you the working code but you still repeat the same. I'd recommend you to start from reading the docs to understand how migrations, relationships etc work because the code in your question shows you didn't read the docs. If you want a working solution, you have it.

Comment: I had to make a separated file for this procedure to work and named it alters after saving the mandatory tables to work.